# How can I check if sorted and rotated array is in ascending or descending order?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I need to check if a sorted and rotated array is in ascending or descending order. I need to know it in order to find a rotation count via modified binary search.

For example:

```
[5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

is in ascending order, but

```
[2, 1, 6, 5, 4, 3]
```

in in descending order

Python implementation would be awesome. Thanks for help!

Comment: how is `[5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4]` sorted or ascending?

Comment: @luigigi it is a "cyclic array".  Think of it as having `array[6] == 5`, and so on.  Obviously the underlying data structure doesn't support that index, but that is what is being represented.

Comment: @Scott thanks, i got it

Comment: @luigigi if you downvoted my post previously, please remove your downvote. If it weren't you, then don't mind this comment. Thanks

Comment: @Rattko, what have you tried so far?  Do you have a partial implementation?

Comment: @Scott I implemented the solution from Dave. The only drawback is that when used with large numbers it takes a bit of time, but I think it's acceptable.

Comment: There exists an implementation of Dave's algorithm that takes the same amount of time no matter how large the list is.  If you put what you have so far, possibly someone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple constant time way is to check any 3 adjacent pairs. At most one contains the boundary, so the majority has the same order as the array.

These can be overlapping. eg, if a,b,c,d are adjacent in the array, the pairs ab, bc, cd are fine.

Wraparound is fine. eg for the array abc, check ab, bc, ca

Comment: edge case: `[2,3,1]`

Comment: @scott wraparound

Comment: `[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3]` ... but probably the OP needs to indicate that all the elements are unique.

Comment: yep. or you need to find 3 pairs of distinct elts which could be linear if mist elts are the same

Answer (score 0):

am providing codes using Java may be you can check out if it would be helpful

```
public class IsSorted {

public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] list ={4,3,2,1};
    System.out.println(isSorted(list));

}

public static int isSorted(int[] a){

    if(a.length==0){
        return 1;
    }
    if(a.length==1){
        return 1;
    }

    int[] holdingArray=new int[a.length];

    for (int i =0; i<a.length; i++){
        holdingArray[i]=a[i];
    }


    int[] virtualIncreasedArray= new int[holdingArray.length];
    int[] virtualDecreasedArray= new int[holdingArray.length];
    sortIncrease(holdingArray);

    for(int i=0; i<holdingArray.length;i++){
        virtualIncreasedArray[i]=holdingArray[i];
    }
    sortDecrease(holdingArray);

    for(int i=0; i<holdingArray.length;i++){
        virtualDecreasedArray[i]=holdingArray[i];
    }

    //check if array is decreasing
    for(int i=0; i<virtualDecreasedArray.length;i++){
        if(virtualDecreasedArray[i]!=a[i]&&virtualIncreasedArray[i]!=a[i]){
            return 0;
        }

    }
    //check if array is increasing


    return 1;
}


static void sortIncrease(int[] a){
    for(int unsorted=a.length-1; unsorted>0; unsorted--){
        for(int i=0; i<unsorted;i++){
            if(a[i]>a[i+1]){
                swap(a,i,i+1);
            }
        }
    }
}


static void sortDecrease(int[] a){
    for(int unsorted=a.length-1; unsorted>0; unsorted--){
        for(int i=0; i<unsorted; i++){
            if(a[i]<a[i+1]){
                swap(a,i,i+1);
            }
        }
    }
}

static void swap(int[] a, int i, int j){
    if(i==j){
        return;
    }
    int temp = a[i];
    a[i]=a[j];
    a[j]=temp;
}
```

}

Comment: it will return 1 if the array is in ascending or descending order otherwise 0